# SQL conditionally select optional column

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I'm given an SQLite db that contains either the columns a,b,c or a,b,c,d based on its version which I'm unaware of.

Is there an elegant way to select d if it exists and not crash if it doesn't?
I can catch the occurring exception when executing the query and try a select without d, but this seems to me like an unsafe way.

Comment: If you want to select all columns why not just do `select * from your_table` ?

Comment: Guess I can't see the wood for the trees. I'll give it a shot and would hope that this is the easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

Use `PRAGMA` function with SQLite - [PRAGMA schema.table_info(table-name);](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info)

```java
  String jdbc = "jdbc:sqlite:your_database.db";
  String tableName = "data_table";
  String columnName = "d";

  try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl);
       Statement statement = conn.createStatement()) {

      // Check that column exists
      ResultSet columns = statement.executeQuery("PRAGMA table_info(" + tableName + ")");
      boolean columnExists = false;
      while (columns.next()) {
          if (columns.getString("name").equalsIgnoreCase(columnName)) {
              columnExists = true;
              break;
          }
      }

      String query;
      if (columnExists) {
          query = "SELECT a, b, c, d FROM " + tableName;
      } else {
          query = "SELECT a, b, c FROM " + tableName;
      }

      ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query);
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something this won't work as it will only use the default value 'no_column' if the content of d is null. d however must exist in this solution.

Comment: oh shoot, you're right - we did this before using PRAGMA. We opened up a connection, then did a check to see column existed. If it did, then we chose which query to run. Let me go back an check

Comment: @redead Revised answer, I think this is what you need